# activemq transportlistener how to use

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using two brokers and create a consumer connection like this

```
 ccf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(new URI("failover://(tcp://0.0.0.0:61617,tcp://0.0.0.0:61618)"));
 ccf.setTransportListener(this);
```

I see in the logs that if one broker goes down the connection reconnects to other failover
But how & where do i catch this event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok transportlistener needs to be set on the ActiveMQConnection

```
 cc = ccf.createConnection();
 cc.start();
 ActiveMQConnection acc = (ActiveMQConnection) cc;
 acc.addTransportListener(this);
```

Now the transportresumed and other callbacks occur.

Answer (score 0):

The transportInterrupted/Resumed is not called when the Ethernet cable is unplugged. It is called when a graceful shutdown is done to the broker..