# Mule ESB Apache ActiveMQ XA Transaction

Tags: transactions, activemq-classic, mule, xa

I am working on an application which takes XML as input and then validate it using XSD if the file is valid, it will be moved to "File_IN_Queue"

Second flow is fetching files from "File_IN_Queue" and does some processing of db logging and all and then again file will be moved to "File_OUT_Queue".

Third flow is fetching files from "File_OUT_Queue" and putting it into some folder using file outbound

Now What I want to implement is if any of this flow fails the file should still stay in queue like, if second flow fails file should stay in "File_IN_Queue" and if third flow fails file should stay in "File_OUT_Queue"

I am using XA transaction bcoz there are many other queues come in to the picture while processing file in second flow like email queue exception queue n all

So, What should i do? how should i implement it??

Right now, in second flow, I have set xa transaction to "Always begin" in file_IN_Queue which is the starting point of the second flow and in third flow, again "Always Begin" in File_OUT_Queue. and all the queues come into the picture in processing are set to "Always Join"

---

### xml config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
    xmlns:smtp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp" xmlns:smtps="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtps"
    xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
    xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.3.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jbossts="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtps http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtps/current/mule-smtps.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp/current/mule-smtp.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts/current/mule-jbossts.xsd">

    <spring:beans>
        <!-- All database access object Beans -->
        <spring:bean id="springApplicationContext" name="springApplicationContext"
            class="com.util.SpringApplicationContext" />
        <spring:bean id="checkPointDAO" name="checkPointDAO"
            class="com.dao.impl.CheckPointDAO"
            scope="prototype" />
        <spring:bean id="buyerDAO" name="buyerDAO"
            class="com.dao.impl.BuyerDAO" />
        <spring:bean id="supplierDAO" name="supplierDAO"
            class="com.dao.impl.SupplierDAO" />
        <spring:bean id="locationDAO" name="locationDAO"
            class="com.dao.impl.LocationDAO" />
        <spring:bean id="shipToDetailDAO" name="shipToDetailDAO"
            class="com.dao.impl.ShipToDetailDAO" />
        <spring:bean id="contactDAO" name="contactDAO"
            class="com.dao.impl.ContactDAO" />
        <spring:bean id="exceptionDAO" name="exceptionDAO"
            class="com.dao.impl.ExceptionDAO" />
        <spring:bean id="messageDAO" name="messageDAO"
            class="com.dao.impl.MessageDAO" />
        <spring:bean id="addressDAO" name="addressDAO"
            class="com.dao.impl.AddressDAO" />
        <spring:bean id="xmlDAO" name="xmlDAO"
            class="com.dao.impl.XmlDAO" />
        <!-- All database access object Beans -->
        <!-- Spring ORM hibernate sessionFactory Bean -->
        <spring:bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <spring:property name="packagesToScan" value="${hibernate.packagesToScan}" />
            <spring:property name="eventListeners">
                <spring:map>
                    <spring:entry key="pre-insert">
                        <spring:bean
                            class="com.listener.PreInsertOrUpdateEventListener"
                            id="preInsertOrUpdateEventListener" />
                    </spring:entry>
                    <spring:entry key="pre-update">
                        <spring:bean
                            class="com.listener.PreInsertOrUpdateEventListener"
                            id="preInsertOrUpdateEventListener" />
                    </spring:entry>
                </spring:map>
            </spring:property>
            <spring:property name="hibernateProperties">
                <spring:props>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${db.driverClassName}</spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${db.url}</spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${db.username}</spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${db.password}</spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</spring:prop>
                    <!-- <spring:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto} 
                        </spring:prop> -->
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">${hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults}
                    </spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">
                        ${hibernate.connection.provider_class}
                    </spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">${hibernate.dbcp.initialSize}
                    </spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.dbcp.maxActive">${hibernate.dbcp.maxActive}
                    </spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">${hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle}
                    </spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">${hibernate.dbcp.minIdle}
                    </spring:prop>
                </spring:props>
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="propertyFileReader" name="propertyFileReader"
            class="com.util.PropertyFileReader"
            init-method="init" />
        <spring:bean id="rboConfig" name="rboConfig"
            class="com.rbo.bean.RboConfiguration">
            <spring:property name="url" value="${url}"></spring:property>
            <spring:property name="account" value="${account}"></spring:property>
            <spring:property name="userId" value="${userId}"></spring:property>
            <spring:property name="password" value="${password}"></spring:property>
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="rboBaseDAO" name="rboBaseDAO"
            class="com.rbo.dao.RboBaseDAO">
            <spring:property name="rboConfig" ref="rboConfig" />
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="rsInfoDAO" name="rsInfoDAO"
            parent="rboBaseDAO" class="com.rbo.dao.RSDAO">
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="rsPartInfoDAO" name="rsPartInfoDAO"
            parent="rboBaseDAO"
            class="com.rbo.dao.RSPartInfoDAO">
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="symphonyInfoResourceComponent" name="symphonyInfoResourceComponent"
            class="com.rbo.component.SymphonyInfoResourceComponent">
            <spring:property name="dao" ref="rsInfoDAO" />
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="orderSplittingComponent" name="orderSplittingComponent"
            class="com.component.OrderSplittingComponent">
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="symphonyPartInfoComponent" name="symphonyPartInfoComponent"
            class="com.rbo.component.SymphonyPartInfoComponent">
            <spring:property name="rsPartInfoDAO" ref="rsPartInfoDAO" />
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="redeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
            <spring:property name="maximumRedeliveries"
                value="${jms.connector.redeliverypolicy.maximumredeliveries}" />
            <spring:property name="initialRedeliveryDelay"
                value="${jms.connector.redeliverypolicy.initialredeliverydelay}" />
            <spring:property name="redeliveryDelay"
                value="${jms.connector.redeliverypolicy.redeliverydelay}" />
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="amqFactory"
            class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory">
            <spring:property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy">
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean></spring:beans>
        <choice-exception-strategy name="Choice_Exception_Strategy">
        <catch-exception-strategy
            when="#[exception.causedBy(${symphony.exception.strategy.class})]"
            doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <logger message="byte to object conersion #[message:payload]"
                level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
            <set-variable variableName="transactionCommand"
                value="#[com.util.TransactionType.ROLLBACK]"
                doc:name=" set transaction command" />
            <component
                class="com.component.TransactionComponent"
                doc:name="Rollback transaction" />
            <custom-transformer
                class="com.transformer.FileNameTransformer"
                doc:name="File Name Transformer" />
            <component
                class="com.component.ExceptionGeneratorComponent"
                doc:name="Exception Generator Component" />
            <set-payload value="#[sessionVars['originalXML']]"
                doc:name="Set Payload" />
            <choice doc:name="Choice">
                <when expression="sessionVars['fileNamePrefix'] == '1$#^'">
                    <processor-chain>
                        <logger message="firstcondition executed" level="INFO"
                            doc:name="Logger" />
                        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="exception_queue"
                            connector-ref="Exception-Email-Processing-JMS-Outbound-connector"
                            doc:name="JMS">
                        </jms:outbound-endpoint>
                    </processor-chain>
                </when>
                <when expression="sessionVars['fileNamePrefix'] == '2$#^'">
                    <processor-chain>
                        <logger message="secondcondition executed" level="INFO"
                            doc:name="Logger" />
                        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="exception_queue"
                            connector-ref="Exception-Email-Processing-JMS-Outbound-connector"
                            doc:name="JMS">
                        </jms:outbound-endpoint>
                    </processor-chain>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <processor-chain>
                        <logger message="otherwisecondition executed" level="INFO"
                            doc:name="Logger" />
                        <set-variable variableName="actionCommand"
                            value="#[com.util.SympEnum.PROCESSED_XML]"
                            doc:name=" set transaction command" />
                        <component
                            class="com.component.XmlLoggingComponent"
                            doc:name="Java" />
                        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="file_out_queue"
                            connector-ref="File-Processing-JMS-Outbound-connector" doc:name="JMS">
                        </jms:outbound-endpoint>
                        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="email_queue"
                            connector-ref="Exception-Email-Processing-JMS-Outbound-connector"
                            doc:name="JMS">
                        </jms:outbound-endpoint>
                    </processor-chain>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
            <component
                class="com.component.ExceptionLoggingComponent"
                doc:name="Exception Logging Component" />
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy
            when="#[exception.causedBy(${symphony.exception.strategy.class.throwable})]">
            <logger message="invalid condition executed" level="INFO"
                doc:name="Logger" />
            <set-variable variableName="actionCommand"
                value="#[com.util.SympEnum.VALID_XML]"
                doc:name=" set transaction command" />
            <component
                class="com.component.XmlLoggingComponent"
                doc:name="Java" />
            <choice doc:name="Choice">
                <when expression="sessionVars['isValid'] == true">
                    <processor-chain>
                        <!--processing-->
                    </processor-chain>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <processor-chain>
                        <logger level="INFO"
                            message="XML is not Validate in XSD Validater The Control is in Exception Strategy Othere Wish part Of XSLT Applicablity "
                            doc:name="Logger" />
                    </processor-chain>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
            <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="file_out_queue"
                connector-ref="File-Processing-JMS-Outbound-connector" doc:name="JMS">
            </jms:outbound-endpoint>
            <component
                class="com.component.ExceptionGeneratorComponent"
                doc:name="Exception Generator Component" />
            <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="email_queue"
                connector-ref="Exception-Email-Processing-JMS-Outbound-connector"
                doc:name="JMS">
            </jms:outbound-endpoint>
            <logger message="Error Occured in File Named : #[header:originalFilename]"
                level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger" />
            <scripting:transformer doc:name="Add no availability error">
                <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                    <scripting:text><![CDATA[org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("").error("Error Trace is : \n",exception)]]></scripting:text>
                </scripting:script>
            </scripting:transformer>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
    <!-- Globle Choice Exception Strategy -->
    <!-- Globle File Endpoints -->
    <!--Http Connector Reference For Exclude Session Params Form Http call -->
    <http:connector name="NoSessionConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
        <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
    </http:connector>
    <jms:activemq-xa-connector name="File-Processing-JMS-Outbound-connector"
        brokerURL="${jms.connector.brokerurl}" validateConnections="${jms.connector.validateconnections}"
        doc:name="Active MQ" persistentDelivery="${jms.connector.persistentdelivery}"
        connectionFactory-ref="amqFactory" maxRedelivery="-1">
        <dispatcher-threading-profile
            maxThreadsActive="${file.processing.jms.connector.maxactivethreads}"
            maxBufferSize="${file.processing.jms.connector.maxbuffersize}"
            poolExhaustedAction="WAIT" />
        <reconnect-forever frequency="${jms.connector.reconnect.forever.frequency}"></reconnect-forever>
    </jms:activemq-xa-connector>
    <jms:activemq-xa-connector name="File-Processing-JMS-Inbound-connector"
        brokerURL="${jms.connector.brokerurl}" validateConnections="${jms.connector.validateconnections}"
        doc:name="Active MQ" persistentDelivery="${jms.connector.persistentdelivery}"
        connectionFactory-ref="amqFactory" maxRedelivery="-1">
        <receiver-threading-profile doThreading="true"
            maxThreadsActive="${file.processing.jms.connector.maxactivethreads}"
            maxBufferSize="${file.processing.jms.connector.maxbuffersize}"
            poolExhaustedAction="WAIT" />
        <reconnect-forever frequency="${jms.connector.reconnect.forever.frequency}"></reconnect-forever>
    </jms:activemq-xa-connector>
    <jms:activemq-xa-connector
        name="Exception-Email-Processing-JMS-Outbound-connector" brokerURL="${jms.connector.brokerurl}"
        validateConnections="${jms.connector.validateconnections}" doc:name="Active MQ"
        persistentDelivery="${jms.connector.persistentdelivery}"
        connectionFactory-ref="amqFactory" maxRedelivery="-1">
        <dispatcher-threading-profile
            maxThreadsActive="${exception.email.processing.jms.connector.maxactivethreads}"
            maxBufferSize="${file.processing.jms.connector.maxbuffersize}"
            poolExhaustedAction="WAIT" />
        <reconnect-forever frequency="${jms.connector.reconnect.forever.frequency}"></reconnect-forever>
    </jms:activemq-xa-connector>
    <jms:activemq-xa-connector
        name="Exception-Email-Processing-JMS-Inbound-connector" brokerURL="${jms.connector.brokerurl}"
        validateConnections="${jms.connector.validateconnections}" doc:name="Active MQ"
        persistentDelivery="${jms.connector.persistentdelivery}"
        connectionFactory-ref="amqFactory" maxRedelivery="-1">
        <receiver-threading-profile doThreading="true"
            maxThreadsActive="${exception.email.processing.jms.connector.maxactivethreads}"
            maxBufferSize="${file.processing.jms.connector.maxbuffersize}"
            poolExhaustedAction="WAIT" />
        <reconnect-forever frequency="${jms.connector.reconnect.forever.frequency}"></reconnect-forever>
    </jms:activemq-xa-connector>
    <!--Http Connector Reference For Exclude Session Params Form Http call -->
    <file:connector name="inputFileConnector" doc:name="File">
        <service-overrides
            messageReceiver="com.util.InputFileMessageReceiver" />
    </file:connector>
    <jbossts:transaction-manager />
    <flow name="input_file_to_mule_in_jms" doc:name="input_file_to_mule_in_jms"
        processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="${symphony.order.input.directory}"
            comparator="${symphony.file.comparator}" moveToDirectory="${symphony.order.processed.directory}"
            fileAge="${symphony.file.age}" doc:name="File" connector-ref="inputFileConnector"
            pollingFrequency="${symphony.inbox.file.polling.frequency}">
            <!--<xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/> -->
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <byte-array-to-object-transformer
            doc:name="Byte Array to Object" />
        <set-session-variable value="#[header:INBOUND:originalFilename]"
            variableName="orderFileName" doc:name="set original file name" />
        <logger message="original file name is : #[sessionVars['orderFileName']]"
            level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <set-session-variable variableName="originalXML"
            value="#[message:payload]" doc:name="Original XML Order" />
        <set-variable variableName="actionCommand"
            value="#[com.util.SympEnum.NEW_XML]"
            doc:name=" set transaction command" />
        <component
            class="com.component.XmlLoggingComponent"
            doc:name="Xml Logging Component" />
        <component
            class="com.component.XMLSchemaValidator"
            doc:name="XML Schema Validator" />
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="file_in_queue"
            connector-ref="File-Processing-JMS-Outbound-connector" doc:name="JMS">
            <!--<xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN"/> -->
        </jms:outbound-endpoint>
        <exception-strategy ref="Choice_Exception_Strategy"
            doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy" />
    </flow>
    <flow name="improved-project" doc:name="improved-project"
        processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <composite-source doc:name="Composite Source">
            <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="file_in_queue"
                connector-ref="File-Processing-JMS-Inbound-connector" doc:name="JMS">
                <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
            </jms:inbound-endpoint>
            <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="exception_queue"
                connector-ref="Exception-Email-Processing-JMS-Inbound-connector"
                doc:name="JMS">
                <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
                <!--<xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" timeout="35000"/> -->
            </jms:inbound-endpoint>
        </composite-source>
        <logger message="original file name is : #[sessionVars['orderFileName']]"
            level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <!-- <set-session-variable variableName="originalXML" value="#[message:payload]" 
            doc:name="Original XML Order" /> -->

        <custom-transformer
            class="com.transformer.XmlToObjectTransformer"
            doc:name="xml to object" />
        <logger level="INFO"
            message="/Message/MessageInfo/MessageSender ID : #[sessionVars['messageObject'].getMessageInfo().getMessageSender()]"
            doc:name="Logger" />
        <set-session-variable value="#[message:payload]"
            variableName="orderPayload" doc:name="Session Variable" />
        <set-session-variable variableName="symphHttpEnableDisable"
            value="#[${project.http.call.enable}]" doc:name="Http Enable / Disable" />
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="sessionVars['symphHttpEnableDisable'] == true">
                <processor-chain>
                    <set-session-variable variableName="condition"
                        value="sessionVars['symphHttpEnableDisable'] == true" doc:name="http Call Enable Disable Condition" />
                    <set-session-variable variableName="result"
                        value="true" doc:name="http Call Enable Disable Result" />
                    <component
                        class="com.component.CheckPointLoggingComponent"
                        doc:description="check point logging" doc:name="check point logging" />
                    <remove-session-variable variableName="condition"
                        doc:name="Remove Session Variable" />
                    <remove-session-variable variableName="result"
                        doc:name="Remove Session Variable" />
                    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
                        host="${project.http.call.host}" port="${project.http.call.port}"
                        path="${project.http.call.path}=#[sessionVars['messageObject'].getMessageInfo().getMessageSender()]"
                        method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="NoSessionConnector" />
                    <byte-array-to-object-transformer
                        doc:name="Byte Array to Object" />
                    <logger message="After Http Call : #[message:payload]"
                        level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
                    <set-session-variable variableName="isPilotCustomer"
                        value="#[xpath:${project.http.call.tradingpartner.status.xpath}]"
                        doc:name="Pilot Customer Status" />
                    <logger
                        message="XML Response Xpath Value : #[sessionVars['isPilotCustomer']]"
                        level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
                    <choice doc:name="Choice">
                        <when expression="sessionVars['isPilotCustomer'] == true">
                            <processor-chain>
                                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"
                                    message="isPilotCustomer check Point pass" />
                                <set-session-variable variableName="condition"
                                    value="sessionVars['isPilotCustomer'] == true" doc:name="http Call Condition" />
                                <set-session-variable variableName="result"
                                    value="true" doc:name="http Call Result" />
                                <component
                                    class="com.component.CheckPointLoggingComponent"
                                    doc:description="check point logging" doc:name="check point logging" />
                                <remove-session-variable variableName="condition"
                                    doc:name="Remove Session Variable" />
                                <remove-session-variable variableName="result"
                                    doc:name="Remove Session Variable" />
                                <flow-ref name="bussnesslogic-project" doc:name="bussnesslogic-project" />
                            </processor-chain>
                        </when>
                        <otherwise>
                            <processor-chain>
                                <set-session-variable variableName="condition"
                                    value="sessionVars['isPilotCustomer'] == true" doc:name="http Call Condition" />
                                <set-session-variable variableName="result"
                                    value="false" doc:name="http Call Result" />
                                <component
                                    class="com.component.CheckPointLoggingComponent"
                                    doc:description="check point logging" doc:name="check point logging" />
                                <remove-session-variable variableName="condition"
                                    doc:name="Remove Session Variable" />
                                <remove-session-variable variableName="result"
                                    doc:name="Remove Session Variable" />
                                <custom-transformer
                                    class="com.transformer.ObjectToXmlTransformer"
                                    doc:name="Object To Xml" />

                                <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="file_out_queue"
                                    connector-ref="File-Processing-JMS-Outbound-connector"
                                    doc:name="JMS">
                                </jms:outbound-endpoint>
                            </processor-chain>
                        </otherwise>
                    </choice>
                </processor-chain>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <processor-chain>
                    <logger level="INFO" message="WithOut Http Call Flow Is ...."
                        doc:name="Logger" />
                    <set-session-variable variableName="condition"
                        value="sessionVars['symphHttpEnableDisable'] == true" doc:name="http Call Enable Disable Condition" />
                    <set-session-variable variableName="result"
                        value="false" doc:name="http Call Enable Disable Result" />
                    <component
                        class="com.component.CheckPointLoggingComponent"
                        doc:description="check point logging" doc:name="check point logging" />
                    <remove-session-variable variableName="condition"
                        doc:name="Remove Session Variable" />
                    <remove-session-variable variableName="result"
                        doc:name="Remove Session Variable" />
                    <flow-ref name="bussnesslogic-project" doc:name="bussnesslogic-project" />
                </processor-chain>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <exception-strategy ref="Choice_Exception_Strategy"
            doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy" />
    </flow>
    <sub-flow name="bussnesslogic-project" doc:name="bussnesslogic-project">
        <set-payload value="#[sessionVars['orderPayload']]"
            doc:name="Set Payload" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"
            message="new message payload: #[message:payload]" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"
            message="After Set Session Var Object in Payload The PayLoad Value Is : #[message:payload]" />
        <component doc:name="RBO project Info Component">
            <spring-object bean="projectInfoResourceComponent"></spring-object>
        </component>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"
            message="After Splitting order The PayLoad Value Is : #[message:payload]" />
        <component doc:name="RBO project Part Info Component">
            <spring-object bean="projectPartInfoComponent"></spring-object>
        </component>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"
            message="After doing DropShip or Available Stock Check, The PayLoad Value Is : #[message:payload]" />
        <component
            class="com.component.CheckPointLoggingComponent"
            doc:description="Check point logging" doc:name="check point logging" />
        <component
            doc:name="Order Splitting Component After DropShip and Available Stock Check">
            <spring-object bean="orderSplittingComponent"></spring-object>
        </component>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"
            message="After Splitting order at last The PayLoad Value Is : #[message:payload]" />
        <set-variable variableName="transactionCommand"
            value="#[com.util.TransactionType.BEGIN]"
            doc:name=" set transaction command" />
        <component
            class="com.component.TransactionComponent"
            doc:name="Begin transaction" />
        <component
            class="com.component.MessageLoggingComponent"
            doc:name="order logging" />
        <custom-transformer
            class="com.transformer.ObjectToXmlTransformer"
            doc:name="Object To Xml Transformer" />
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="file_out_queue"
            connector-ref="File-Processing-JMS-Outbound-connector" doc:name="JMS">
            <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" timeout="35000" />
        </jms:outbound-endpoint>
        <set-variable variableName="transactionCommand"
            value="#[com.util.TransactionType.COMMIT]"
            doc:name=" set transaction command" />
        <component
            class="com.component.TransactionComponent"
            doc:name="Commit transaction" />
    </sub-flow>
    <flow name="mule_out_jms_to_output_file" doc:name="mule_out_jms_to_output_file"
        processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="file_out_queue"
            connector-ref="File-Processing-JMS-Inbound-connector" doc:name="JMS">
            <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/> 
        </jms:inbound-endpoint>
        <logger level="INFO" message="activemq_to_fileFlow1 : #[message:payload]"
            doc:name="Logger" />
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="${project.order.output.directory}"
            outputPattern="#[header:SESSION:orderFileName]" responseTimeout="10000"
            doc:name="File" />
        <set-variable variableName="actionCommand"
            value="#[com.util.SympEnum.OUT_XML]"
            doc:name=" set transaction command" />
        <component
            class="com.component.XmlLoggingComponent"
            doc:name="Java" />
        <exception-strategy ref="Choice_Exception_Strategy"
            doc:name="Reference
        Exception Strategy" />
    </flow>

</mule>
```

this is my current config. and when I stop the mule application and start it again it works fine it takes pending messages from the queue and process it properly but when I close the ActiveMQ broker and start it again it doesn't work properly, in this case I have to restart my application also and still it doesn't process all the files.

Comment: Can you share your xml configuration?

Comment: please look at the xml config

Comment: possible duplicate of [activemq transportlistener how to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791984/activemq-transportlistener-how-to-use)